# Query where there is no relation for specific record through pivot?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Have been trying to solve this problem for hours but just can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the show method where I want to change my query

```
    public function show(DitoNumber $ditoNumber)
{
    $germanDismantlers = GermanDismantler::paginate(100);

    $relatedDismantlers = $ditoNumber->germanDismantlers;

    return view('admin.dito-numbers.show', compact('ditoNumber', 'germanDismantlers', 'relatedDismantlers'));
}
```

The problem is that I do not want to get the german dismantlers I am also getting through the relationship. So instead of just getting all the records and paginating them on the first line of the method I would prefer to exclude the ones that are already connect to a dito number.

Where this gets a bit complicated is that it is connected through a pivot table

Here is the table

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('dito_number_german_dismantler', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('dito_number_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreignId('german_dismantler_id')->constrained();

        $table->primary(['dito_number_id', 'german_dismantler_id'], 'pk');
    });
}
```

Here is my relationship for connecting germanDismantlers to ditoNumbers

```
public function germanDismantlers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(GermanDismantler::class);
}
```

And the oppisite

```
public function ditoNumbers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(DitoNumber::class);
}
```

UPDATE
Here I am trying to do the search. This query works fine if there is no search or if it's by the plaintext but the problem is that if it is by either the commercial name or data (where it is going to the orWhere) It's ignoring the whereDoesntHave we just created and returning related dismantlers again

```
    if($search) {
         $germanDismantlers = GermanDismantler::whereDoesntHave(
                'ditoNumbers', function($query) use($ditoNumber, $search){
                    $query->where('id', $ditoNumber->id);
                    $query->where(function($innerQuery) use($search) {
                        $innerQuery->where('manufacturer_plaintext', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
                        $innerQuery->orWhere('commercial_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
                        $innerQuery->orWhere('date_of_allotment_of_type_code_number', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
                    });
                }
            )
                ->paginate(100)
                ->withQueryString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF I understand it correct - you want to get all `GermanDismantler`(s) which are not associated with a `DitoNumber` and then paginate them right?

You can try the following query to get the desired output

```php
public function show(DitoNumber $ditoNumber)
{
    //Get only those GermanDismantler records which are not associated with
    //the $ditoNumber record which is resolved from request parameter
    //Assume: id is PK column on table for DitoNumber
    $germanDismantlers = GermanDismantler::whereDoesntHave(
        'ditoNumbers', 
        fn($query) => $query->where('id', $ditoNumber->id)
    )
    ->paginate(100);

    $relatedDismantlers = $ditoNumber->germanDismantlers;

    return view('admin.dito-numbers.show', compact('ditoNumber', 'germanDismantlers', 'relatedDismantlers'));
}
```

###### Update:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dito_numbers.german_dismantler_id' in 'where clause' Is it because dito_numbers does not have any fk? the fk's are both in the pivot table

It's because you have defined the relationship on `GermanDismantler` as **hasMany** instead of **belongsToMany**.

For Many-to-Many relationship both model classes should have **belongsToMany** relationships.

Change the relationship to

```php
//GermanDismantler.php
public function ditoNumbers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(DitoNumber::class);
}
```

[Laravel Docs - Querying Relationship Absence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)

[Laravel Docs - Eloquent Relationships - Many-to-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: It's close but the difference is I don't want the GermanDismantlers associated with the specific ditoNumber I am taking into the show method. So the output should be the opposite of $ditoNumber->germanDismantlers @Donkarnash

Comment: @nikulas13 Have updated the answer. Please check and see if that's what you intend.

Comment: Thank you for the update I am indeed closer to solving it :) I am currently gettting this error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dito_numbers.german_dismantler_id' in 'where clause' Is it because dito_numbers does not have any fk? the fk's are both in the pivot table

Comment: @nikulas13 What error?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dito_numbers.german_dismantler_id' in 'where clause' Is it because dito_numbers does not have any fk? the fk's are both in the pivot table

Comment: @nikulas13 Have updated answer to fix the relationship on **GermanDismantler** model. Check - should work now

Comment: Thank you so much! Do I understand it correctly that both should have belongsToMany? :) Just read the updated answer in detail thank you!

Comment: @nikulas13 Yes for **Many-to-Many** relationships both models should have `belongsToMany** . Have added link to Laravel docs

Comment: appreciate the help so far and don't want to spam you with my problems but if you are interested in taking I have updated showcasing a problem I have when I try to talk on a search feature to the query.

Comment: @nikulas13 Please do not add supplementary question here, as won't get desired attention and is against SO convention. Post a new question with the complete controller method the model relationships. That way the question will get the desired attention and won't violate SO conventions. Just remove the update part and post a new question. You may even message me the link when the question is posted, will try my best to help you out.

Comment: @ Donkarnash Was actually able to solve it myself after tinkering a bit with the query and moving the second nested where outside of the whereDoesntHave. Not sure why that works as the way I see it it should not make a difference but I guess I have a lot to learn about relationships and queries and Laravel :)